# How To Attach Custom Map On MapView? [Android]

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, customization, overlays

I have a question about Mapview.  I have an image which is a map of
small area (ex: http://goo.gl/tKQM6).

Can i use this image in mapview? if it is possible can i use overlays
and other mapview actions on it? I can add different images for different zoom levels.

If there is no way to do this with Google Maps, are there any other way to do
this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully drawn a circule on map.
I override the on draw method of **ItemizedOverlay** for this and perform some canvas and paint operations in it.
Like that:

```
public class DepartureItemizdOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay { 
.......
......


public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow,
long when) {  

    Paint paint;      
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    float strockWidth = Departure.gpsAccuracy / ACCURACY_width_constant;
        if(strockWidth >= MAX_STROCK_WIDTH)
            strockWidth = MAX_STROCK_WIDTH;
    Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();
    Point point = new Point();
    projection.toPixels(mOverlays.get(GPS_DETECTED_GP_INDEX).getPoint(), point);
    float circleRadius = (float)         (projection.metersToEquatorPixels
    (Departure.MAX_DISTANCE_gps_dep) * (1/
    Math.cos(Math.toRadians(mOverlays.
    get(GPS_DETECTED_GP_INDEX).getPoint().
    getLatitudeE6()/1E6))));

    paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
    paint.setAlpha(30);
    canvas.drawCircle(point.x, point.y, circleRadius, paint);

    paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(MAX_STROCK_WIDTH);
        paint.setAlpha(100);
    canvas.drawCircle(point.x, point.y, circleRadius, paint);


    mapView.postInvalidate();


    return super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow, when);  
}

.....

}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer but i need to know that is it possible to use custom map image in MapView not custom overlay image. I want to import my map images to Mapview